# Is there any reason you would loop through an array (or some kind of iterable object) twice?

Tags: ruby, iterator, each

Is there any reason you would loop through an array (or some kind of iterable object) twice?

**example double loop:**

```
array.each do |array_object|
  # do some stuff with array object
end.each do |array_object_other_loop|
  # do some other stuff
end
```

I have not seen any usages like this but ruby will allow you to do it.

Comment: A better question might be why wouldn't it allow you to do it?

Comment: Not only is it possible, but in a sense it is the essence of the language, statements like `obj.select {...}.map {...}...`.

Comment: possibly, I mean I get why its possible (basically its just re-using the enumerator so there is no reason why not) but really i'm trying to figure out why you would ever want to like is there ever a usage of this that would make sense?

Comment: What @CarySwoveland said with the addition that `each` is just a method that happens to return its receiver; `each` isn't any sort of special syntax, it is just a method like any other.

Comment: Jesse, I'm not sure your question is not really specific to Ruby.  Suppose, for example you wanted to sum all elements of an array greater than 10.  In Ruby, you could `array.select {|e| e>10}.reduce(:+)` or you could just `array.reduce {|e,t| t + (e>10 ? e : 0)}`.  You may have reasons to prefer one over the other, but you have a similar choice in most other languages, though the syntax may not resemble Ruby's way of chaining operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is simply an effect of every expression returning a value in Ruby. It just so happens that `each` returns the original collection, so you can call `each` on that again. It does not mean that this was designed with this specific scenario in mind, but having `each` return the collection itself is certainly a sign that the authors of the language encourage such use.

I could think of a situation where you create a collection on the fly, then iterate over it immediately, then again; without ever writing the collection to a variable. The difference to just looping over an element inside the `each` would then be the order of execution. For example:

```
%w[a b c].each do |char|
  puts char
end.each do |char|
  puts char
end

# a
# b
# c
# a
# b
# c

%w[a b c].each do |char|
  2.times do
    puts char
  end
end

# a
# a
# b
# b
# c
# c
```

That said, we could ask a million of such questions like

> Would it ever make sense to `puts puts` something?

Of course `puts` returns the original object as well, so you can `puts` it again, but it sure ain’t pretty. Ruby is a very flexible language and all of these facilities are there to allow you to express freely what you mean. If in doubt, always stick with the most obvious way of doing things and try to make the code reveal its intention.

Answer (score 2):

An example that immediately came to my mind is when you want to draw a table on a terminal with the columns aligned. In order to figure out the column width, you need to iterate through the rows once, at which time you cannot do the padding. The padding has to be done in the second iteration.

```
rows = ["hi", "hello", "good morning"]
column_width = 0
rows
.each{|column| column_width = [column_width, column.length].max}
.each{|column| puts "|" + column.center(column_width) + "|"}
```

Output:

```
|     hi     |
|   hello    |
|good morning|
```

You cannot put the blocks of two `each` above together.